# The term 'mysql.server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, mysql

> **mysql.server : The term 'mysql.server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

When I try to start `mysql.server start` it gets me an error as you can see.
I've installed flask, mysqldb, passlib successfully using those commands on vscode terminal ( on windows 10) :

```
pip install flask
```

Successfully installed flask-2.0.1

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
```

and it gets me a successfully installed message, then I type:

```
pip install passlib
```

again : Successfully installed passlib-1.7.4

but when I try to start mysql server with this command `mysql.server start`
then I get an error message telling me :
**mysql.server : The term 'mysql.server' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- mysql.server start
- CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql.server:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

So please can you help me !

Answer (score 1):

You mention that your environment is Windows 10.

To start mysql server on Windows you need to open CMD window (`start -> run -> cmd`) and execute:

```
C:\> 
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld"
```

Possibly configure the currect path if your mysql installation is different in version or location.

See here for more info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html

Comment: it gets me this message